# Comments block realization with js

Tags: javascript

I need to do a block with comments to the photos. Comments are taken from the server and i render them like this:

```
class Comment {
    constructor(date, text){
        this.commentElement = this.create(date, text);
    }

    create(dateValue, textValue){
        const commentItem = document.createElement('div');
        commentItem.classList.add('popup__comment');
        commentItem.classList.add('comment');

        const commentDate = document.createElement('span');
        commentDate.classList.add('comment__date');
        commentDate.textContent = dateValue;

        const commentText = document.createElement('span');
        commentText.classList.add('comment__text');
        commentText.textContent = textValue;

        commentItem.appendChild(commentDate);
        commentItem.appendChild(commentText);

        return commentItem;
    }
}

class CommentList {
    constructor(container, items) {
        this.container = container;
        this.items = items;

        this.render();
    }

    addComment(date, text){
        const {commentElement} = new Comment(date, text);
        this.container.appendChild(commentElement);
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.items);
        this.items.comments.forEach((comment) => {
            const dateToFormat = new Date(comment.date);
            const year = dateToFormat.getFullYear();
            const month = dateToFormat.getMonth();
            const date = dateToFormat.getDate();
            const finalDate = `${date}.${month + 1}.${year}`;

            this.addComment(finalDate, comment.text);
        })
    }
}

let commentList;
api.getPictures()
.then((data) => {
    data.forEach((item) => {
        fetch(`example.com`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            if (data.comments && data.comments.length) {
            commentList = new CommentList(commentContainer, data)
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    })
}) 
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The problem is, only 2 of 6 photos have comments, but all comments render under all the photos. How can i render comments only with photos they belong? Console.log(this.items) shows the exactly that objects with comments, which i need though

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Maybe replace your `api` call with the data that is returned from it.